# How can I route data cables through the ceiling?

Tags: data-wiring

I'm wiring my new home, and I have a camera system (BNC but looks like a stero cable in diameter) and ethernet cables that I've run to the attic space.  Everything was going great until summer hit, and the temps in the attic started to become too hot for the routers.  I want to move them into a closet, so my plan is to just drill a hole in the ceiling and drop the wires down.  There are quite a few, 27 cables that I need to route.

My question is, when I make a 4" hole in the ceiling that goes directly to my attic, will that cause issues with my heating and cooling? Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Have you considered using boxes with faceplates on them?

Comment: I had not.  You think a double gang box would work?

Comment: It may take 4-5 gangs or so of box....(wallplates are probably going to be the limiting factor)

Comment: You definitely want to use some sort of junction box for fire safety and to prevent insect infiltration, and use extra insulation atop the box. A foam gasket around the holes, or just a bit of fiberglass insulation, should help.

Comment: I really wish there was a device for this.  Any thoughts on what would be better, through ceiling or through wall?

Comment: I ended up going with the junction box, through the wall, instead of a hole in the ceiling.  I just cut a huge hole in the box for all the wires with a hole saw, and the gaps are pretty small.